# How to resolve the error "mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied" for the following CNN architecture?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I am trying to implement a `Conv1d` model with Batch Normalization but I am getting the error :

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-ef6e122ea50c> in <module>()
----> 1 test()
      2 for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
      3   train(epoch)
      4   test()

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1751     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight):
   1752         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1753     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1754 
   1755 

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x140 and 100x10)
```

I use a batch size of 32, with the number of features of the data being 40. I've been trying to calculate where the `32 x 140` is coming from but I wasn't able to do that. Here is the architecture for the CNN I am trying to use:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        #self.flatten=nn.Flatten()
        self.net_stack=nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=25, kernel_size=5, stride=2), #applying batch norm
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(25, affine=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=25, out_channels=20, kernel_size=5, stride=2), #applying batch norm
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(20, affine=True),
            nn.Flatten()
            nn.Linear(20*5, 10),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1))

    def forward(self,x):
        # result=self.net_stack(x[None])
        result=self.net_stack(x[:, None, :])
        return result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fully-connnected should change from:

```py
nn.Linear(20*5, 10)
```

to:

```py
nn.Linear(20*7, 10)
```

Why?

If your input data length is 40, then (`B` is the batch size):

- Output after first conv (K=25): `B x 25 x 18`
- Output after second conv (K=20): `B x 20 x 7`
- Output after `nn.Flatten()`: `B x 140`, i.e., if B=32, then `32x140`

Comment: As for where the 18 and 7 come from in this answer, the formula is output_width = (input_width - kernel_size)/2 + 1, where input_width = number of features. So output_width of first conv = (40-5)/2 + 1 = 18.5, and output_width of second conv = (18-5)/2 + 1 = 7.5.